# Django: Why im getting NameError in shell if I have correct import in admin.py

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset

I don't really understand why i get NameError when i try run Post.objects.all() in shell.(by using django_extensions)

I made migrations and I see posts_post table on db(work fine) and i can do CRUD operations in running applicationon local server.

Below is my code and error message.

posts app

admin.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

settings.py:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_extensions',
    'posts.apps.PostsConfig'
]
```

shell

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 Post.objects.all()
NameError: name 'Post' is not defined
```

Comment: Are you accessing the shell with `./manage.py shell_plus` ? The usual [`shell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#shell) from `django-admin` is different from the one provided by `django-extensions`: https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html#shell-plus

Comment: You haven't imported the `Post` class in your shell - it won't be available unless you import it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import model first, so write it as following:

```
from some_app_name.models import Post
Post.objects.all()
```

And don't write <s>`from .models import Post`</s> as it requires appname.

Example: If the appname is `posts` so you should write:

```
from posts.models import Post
Post.objects.all()
```